# How to convert Pyspark Dataframe to Pandas on Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have intermediate pyspark dataframe which I want to convert to Pandas on Spark Dataframe (not just toPandas()).
I have gone through the official docs and found out `pandas_api()` does the job for me. But when I try use it says, `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pandas_api'`

```
          type(df)
Out[115]: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame


          df.pandas_api()


AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pandas_api'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2644367454426097> in <module>
----> 1 df.pandas_api()

/[REDACTED]/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1798         """
   1799         if name not in self.columns:
-> 1800             raise AttributeError(
   1801                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
   1802         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pandas_api'
```

Pyspark version: 3.2.1

Comment: If I use `toPandas` it will be just plain pandas dataframe (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame). I wanna create pandas-on-spark dataframe. Have a look at this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/quickstart_ps.html

Comment: It works for me pyspark==3.3.1. `df1 = df.pandas_api(); type(df1)` gives `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame`

Comment: @Corralien - Thanks for checking out. I am using this on Databricks environment. Does it cause the issue? Moreover I am not sure from which version pandas_api is allowed. Let me verify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas API on Spark is supported from Spark 3.2.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34849), but the method you try to use on Dataframe was implemented later and introduced in the version 3.3.0.

It was introduced with this ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37337 in commit: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/bc7d55fc1046a55df61fdb380629699e9959fcc6

Which basically makes changes to naming and depreciation/undepreciation of the methods.

```
### What changes were proposed in this pull request?
The PR is proposed to:

- Undeprecate (Spark)DataFrame.to_koalas 

- Deprecate (Spark)DataFrame.to_pandas_like and introduce (Spark)DataFrame.pandas_api instead.

### Why are the changes needed?
Currently, (Spark)DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark is too long to memorize and inconvenient to call.
With the proposal of the PR, we may improve the user experience and make APIs more developer-friendly.

### Does this PR introduce _any_ user-facing change?
Yes.

(Spark)DataFrame.pandas_api is introduced.
(Spark)DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark is deprecated.
(Spark)DataFrame.to_koalas is undeprecated.
```

For the Spark 3.2.1 you can check those:

```
type(df.to_koalas())

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:2964: FutureWarning: DataFrame.to_koalas is deprecated. Use DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark instead.
  warnings.warn(
Out[5]: pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame
```

or this one:

```
type(df.to_pandas_on_spark())

Out[6]: pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame
```